# Virtual Network Adapter Library for .NET

Tags: .net, vpn, loopback

I want to write a VPN program in .NET. I'm not sure how to create the required virtual network adapter. I've looked into the tuntap driver, which OpenVPN uses, but it's .NET bindings are poor to nonexistent. I've also heard that Microsoft's built-in Loopback driver might be able to do this, but I don't know how to "connect" to it so that my application can manage packets sent through the adapter.

How can I create and use a virtual network adapter from .NET?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the VPN configured in windows you can use the following command to connect to it:

```
Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "YOUR_VPN YOUR_Username YOUR_Password");
```

And later disconnect from it:

```
Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "YOUR_VPN /d");
```